# How to read JMeter Test Cmd Line Parameters from JSR223/Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, command-prompt, beanshell, jsr223

I have wrote a JMeter test and I want to run it in Command Line with some parameters, let's say ThreadNumber.

How do I read it in JSR223/BeanShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send property in command line using `-J` which adds new property

```
 -JthreadNum=100
```

Inside  [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) use the value using [`__P` function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in Number of Users(threads) field

```
 ${__P(threadNum)}
```

> simplified property function which is intended for use with properties defined on the command line.

Use `props` to get properry  in JSR223/BeanShell

```
  props.get("threadNum")
```

- Note you may set ramp up same as thread number property

> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.