# Configurable number of threads in jmeter ThreadGroup

Tags: jmeter

let say i want to test the same http request for 10 users, 25 users ,50 users and 100 users separately and generate a report for each group of users.
One solution is to manually create as many thread group as a number of group of users:

- ThreadGroup for 10 users
- ThreadGroup for 25 users
- ...

is there any other solution to create this plan in jmeter?

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222816/how-to-read-jmeter-test-cmd-line-parameters-from-jsr223-beanshell/50225221#50225221

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the desired number of threads using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```

   [image]
2. When you will be [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) you will be able to pass the number of threads using [`-J` command-line argument like](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override):

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=10 -n -t test.jmx -l 10-threads-result.jtl

   jmeter -Jthreads=25 -n -t test.jmx -l 25-threads-result.jtl

   etc.
   ```